# How to run CMU Phoenix Parser

Tags: parsing, compilation

I need to use CMU Phoenix semantic parser.

In its documentation, it does not give information about which programs/compilers are needed to compile a grammar. Compile script is pasted below. If you can identify what type of script it is you may help me.

I am using Windows 7. The file which contains the code below does not have any extension. In manual of the parser, it just states that run the file by writing file name from the command line. I go to the directory from command line where this file located, but it does nothing when I call compile command. It just give error that there is no command called compile.

If this is a perl script (I am not sure), Perl installed on my computer. Just extra information the parser is written with C.

I would appreciate, if you recommend any source or tutorial to run this parser.

Thanks

```
#!/bin/tcsh

# compile grammars in .
# put compiled nets in file $TASK.net
# set PHOENIX to point to root of Phoenix system
# set LIBS to .gra files to load from $PHOENIX/Grammars
# if SingleFile == 1, then all grammar rules are in file $TASK.gra
# if SingleFile == 0, then compiles all files in dir with extension .gra

set TASK="EX"
set LIBS="date_time.gra number.gra next.gra"
set PHOENIX="../../../Phoenix"
@ SingleFile = 0

set DIR=`pwd`

# if separate files, pack into single file
if( $SingleFile == 0 ) then
#   if file exists, save it as *.old
if ( -e $TASK.gra )  then
    mv $TASK.gra $TASK.gra.old
endif
cat *.gra > xxx
mv xxx $TASK.gra
endif

# append lib grammars to file
cd $PHOENIX/Grammars
cat $LIBS >> $DIR/$TASK.gra
cd $DIR

# remove old compiled files
rm base.dic
rm nets
rm log
rm $TASK.net

# create list of nets to be compiled
cat $TASK.gra | $PHOENIX/Scripts/mk_nets.perl > nets

# compile grammar output messages to file "log"
echo "compiling grammar"
$PHOENIX/ParserLib/compile_grammar -f $TASK > log
grep ERROR log
grep WARN log

# flag leaf nodes for extracts function
echo "flagging leaf nodes"
$PHOENIX/ParserLib/concept_leaf -grammar $TASK.net
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Linux shell script. You should either run it on a Linux box, virtual linux machine or under Cygwin.

Google these three solutions and check which one suits you best.